# How to track an image file (loaded from computer) in a screenshot using Pyhton OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot

I'm trying to write a program that identify an specified image in a screenshot.
But the tracking rectangle keeps showing in the top left corner for some reason.
And the image I provide is not there for sure.

Here's the python code I modified from:
https://steam.oxxostudio.tw/category/python/ai/ai-tracker.html
Caould anyone help me?
I'm guessing that `tracker.init` and `tracker.update` should probably have same input `frame`?
But I don't want to select the image from screenshot (which is named as "frame" in the code) manually using `cv2.selectROI`.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
tracking = False  



bounding_box = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}

sct = mss()

while True:
    frame = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    frame = np.array(frame)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(1920,1080))
    keyName = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if keyName == ord('a'):
        ready_img = cv2.imread("ready.png")
        ready_img = cv2.cvtColor(ready_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        ready_img = cv2.resize(ready_img,(175,138))
        area = (0, 0, 175, 138)

        tracker.init(ready_img, area)
        # print(area)
        tracking = True
    
    if keyName == ord('q'):
        break

    if tracking:
        success, point = tracker.update(frame)
        if success:
            p1 = [int(point[0]), int(point[1])]
            p2 = [int(point[0] + point[2]), int(point[1] + point[3])]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,0,255), 3)

    cv2.imshow('screen shot', frame)
```

Comment: you are right, you shouldn't initialise tracker on one image and update on other image.

Comment: If you don't want to manually select roi, then you can use object detection to detect object in the first frame then assign roi to tracker